# ¿Cómo cargar contenido por AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Ejercicio**

> Haga una agenda WEB la cual mostrará el listado de todos los contactos guardados en la agenda y permitirá almacenar nuevos contactos.
> De cada contacto se almacenarán su nombre, apellido y teléfono.
>
> Utilizando la función fetch usted podrá obtener mediante el método HTTP GET el listado de todos los contactos almacenados en la agenda en formato JSON mediante el siguiente enlace: `http://www.raydelto.org/agenda.php`. De igual modo, invocando la misma URL mediante el método POST de HTTP y enviando un cuerpo JSON con los campos nombre , apellido, telefono usted podrá agregar nuevos contactos a su agenda.

Aquí el código que tengo hecho:

```js
    function getDatos(){
        fetch("http://www.raydelto.org/agenda.php").then(
            function(captura){
                return captura.json();
            }
        ).then(
            function(captura)
            {
               var txtNombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
               var txtApellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido");
               var txtTelefono = document.getElementById("txtTelefono");
                txtNombre.innerHTML = captura[0].nombre;
                txtApellido.innerHTML = captura[0].apellido;
                txtTelefono.innerHTML = captura[0].telefono;
            }
        )
    }
```

```css
    .contacto
    {
        size: 15px;
        background-color: #ffe4c4;
        border-radius: 12%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
    .titulo
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 18px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
    
    .valor
    {
        font-weight: 90%;;
    
    }
    .fila{
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
    <html>  
        <head>  
            <title> Agenda de Contactos</title>
            <script src = "js/index.js"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/index.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <body onload="getDatos()">
                <h1>Agenda Multicapas</h1>
    
                <div class="contacto">
                    <div class ="fila">
                        <div class="titulo">Nombre:</div>
                       <div class="valor" id="txtNombre"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="fila">
                        <div class="titulo">Apellido:</div>
                    <div class="valor" id="txtApellido"></div>
                     </div>
                    
    
                    <div class="fila">
                        <div class="titulo">Telefono:</div>
                    <div class="valor" id="txtTelefono"></div>
                     </div>    
                    </div>
            </body>  
    </html>
```

Pero en *Javascript* no estoy logrando exactamente lo que me pidieron.

Comment: @BetaM esto es lo que tengo hecho

Comment: usa el boton [edit]... agrega lo que hiciste, y que problema particular tuviste...

Comment: @gbianchi , ya he editado el codigo que tengo hecho

Comment: Tienes dos etiquetas `<body>`

Comment: Si realizas un **console.log(captura)** cuando obtienes la data que te muestra ???